# How do i link a xml file with several nodes and subnodes?

Tags: javascript, xml

am looking for a javascript that will load an xml file and will display something like rectangules with links based on the xml child nodes, parents linked to childs and subnodes linked to nodes. how would i be able to do this?

Comment: this should output something as this pic --> http://development4.sytes.net/html5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with AJAX.

First, create a function that will pull information from your XML file:

```
function loadXMLdoc(url) {
  var ajaxRequest;
  try {
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch(e) {
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try {
      ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
      try {
    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch(e) {
        // Something went wrong
    alert("Your browser broke!");
    return false;
      }
    }
  }
  // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
  ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (ajaxRequest.readyState === 4) {
  if (ajaxRequest.status === 200) {
        // a hidden div to display the result
    var result = document.getElementById('result');
    result.style.display = 'block';
    result.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = 'An error has occurred making the request';
  }
    }
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url, true);
    ajaxRequest.send();
  };
}
```

From here, you can start grabbing data from your XML file. Inside your `if (ajaxRequest.status === 200) { }` statement, you can start calling elements:

```
var elem = ajaxRequest.responseXML.getElementById('elem');
var parents = elem.parentNodes;
var children = parents.childNodes;
```

It's up to you exactly how you'd like to format this and what data you're grabbing, but this should be a good starting point for you.

Comment: You're welcome. I realize it's a lot to take in, but AJAX is really powerful and the best way to access an XML file w/ JavaScript.